# Paypal Authorization throws: Can not access to this resource

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-marketplaces

I am working on Paypal Marketplace. I want to create a merchant(seller account) for my account(Partner Account). But when i call POST `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/partner-referrals` API than it throws AUTHORIZATION_ERROR: You are not allowed to access this resource. I have passed a token in Header by generating it `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token`

Below data i passed using Postman:

```
{
  "customer_data": {
  "customer_type": "MERCHANT",
  "person_details": {
    "email_address": "mca.dipak-facilitator@gmail.com",
    "name": {
    "prefix": "Mrs.",
    "given_name":"Dipak",
    "surname": "Bhalodiya",
    "middle_name": "Prakash"
    },
    "phone_contacts": [
    {
      "phone_number_details": {
      "country_code": "91",
      "national_number": "8585868489"
      },
      "phone_type": "HOME"
    }
    ],
    "home_address": {
    "line1": "11, outer ring road",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "country_code": "US",
    "postal_code": "560103"
    },
    "date_of_birth": {
    "event_type": "BIRTH",
    "event_date": "1987-12-29T23:59:59.999Z"
    },
    "nationality_country_code": "US",
    "identity_documents": [
    {
      "type": "SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER",
      "value": "ABCDEF34646",
      "partial_value": false,
      "issuer_country_code": "US"
    }
    ]
  },
  "business_details": {
    "phone_contacts": [
    {
      "phone_number_details": {
      "country_code": "91",
      "national_number": "9740216087"
      },
      "phone_type": "FAX"
    }
    ],
    "business_address": {
    "line1": "11, outer ring road",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "country_code": "US",
    "postal_code": "560103"
    },
    "business_type": "PROPRIETORSHIP",
    "category": "1004",
    "sub_category": "2025",
    "names": [
    {
      "type": "LEGAL",
      "name": "DIPAK STORE"
    }
    ],
    "business_description": "Arts and handicrafts",
    "event_dates": [
    {
      "event_type": "ESTABLISHED",
      "event_date": "2009-01-31T13:59:45Z"
    }
    ],
    "website_urls": [
    "https://www.skyproductivity.com"
    ],
    "annual_sales_volume_range": {
    "minimum_amount": {
        "value": "2000",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "maximum_amount": {
        "value": "3000",
        "currency": "USD"
    }
    },
    "average_monthly_volume_range": {
        "minimum_amount": {
        "value": "2000",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "maximum_amount": {
        "value": "3000",
        "currency": "USD"
    }
    },
    "identity_documents": [
    {
      "type": "TAX_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER",
      "value": "ABCDEF34646",
      "partial_value": false,
      "issuer_country_code": "US"
    }
    ],
    "email_contacts": [
    {
      "email_address": "customer-service@example.com",
      "role": "CUSTOMER_SERVICE"
    }
    ]
  },
  "financial_instrument_data": {
    "bank_details": [
        {
          "nick_name": "Bank of America",
          "account_number": "130385868974",
          "account_type": "CHECKING",
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "identifiers": [
              {
            "type": "ROUTING_NUMBER_1",
            "value": "325272063"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
  },
  "preferred_language_code": "en_US",
  "primary_currency_code": "USD",
  "referral_user_payer_id": {
    "type": "PAYER_ID",
    "value": "2281707"
  },
  "partner_specific_identifiers": [
    {
    "type": "TRACKING_ID",
    "value": "130370723501"
    }
  ]
  },
  "requested_capabilities": [
  {
    "capability": "API_INTEGRATION",
  "api_integration_preference": {
    "partner_id": "2281707", //My own Partner Id
    "rest_api_integration": {
      "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
      "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY"
    },
    "rest_third_party_details": {
      "partner_client_id": "My Test Account Client ID", //My Client ID of Test Account
      "feature_list": [
        "PAYMENT",
        "REFUND"
      ]
    }
  }
  }
  ],
  "web_experience_preference": {
  "partner_logo_url": "https://www.example.com/logo/",
  "return_url": "http://localhost/skyinvoice/htdocs/",
  "action_renewal_url": "http://localhost/skyinvoice/htdocs/"
  },
  "collected_consents": [
  {
    "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
    "granted": true
  }
  ],
  "products": [
  "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal Marketplaces are limited release product and it is available only for approved Merchant. so they granted permission on your client ID to use the API in your sandbox environment. So, I would like to suggest, if you facing the error like as above than kindly mail to paypal.

Comment: @BandishDave You will already get it in your test account. It will be there.

Comment: Thank you for replaying me.... can you please give me particular menu where i can get partner and tracking id??.... because i didn't find anywhere in my test account.

Comment: @mayurpanchal Yes you can test it on your sandbox account.